# What's the most efficient ETag generation given the following possibilities?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, go

I've been fooling around with caching http responses lately in Go and I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way possible to generate proper ETags.

Right now I have the following data available:

1. The name of a template being rendered for when I ever render templates.
2. The dynamic data being passed into a template or response for json responses.
3. The entire response body.
4. The length of the body.
5. Something that I might be missing?

After some thinking I came to the conclusion that if I combine the name of the template and the dynamic data being produced this should in theory create a legit unique ETag with the least amount of overhead but I don't know how nasty this will get if I start wanting to return like 30kb of html worth of database results.

I'm using a crc32 routine from Go's stdlib to generate the ETag from the data I pass into it.

Is there a better way to generate ETags, or even cache dynamic data? I can't just monitor the last-modified time of a file because the the data can change without the file changing.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to use something that is cheap to calculate as an ETag.  The reason for this is that if the client sends a conditional request (e.g. via the `If-None-Match` HTTP request header), you can decide whether it is appropriate to send a `304 Not Modified` response without having to do all the processing for the page.

For example, if you have some kind of revision identifier for the content of a page, then that might make a good ETag.

If you will need to do all the work necessary to render the page just to generate an ETag, then you may as well just use a hash of the rendered page content, or no ETag at all.

Comment: Yeah I have no revision ID, I don't want to complicate URLs with checksums or some other metadata. That is why I'm trying to figure out the best way to generate it.

Definitely open to suggestions.

Comment: Well, if you're hoping to get the most out of HTTP caching, then it is worth looking at whether you can structure your data to facilitate it.  If you can't make your data fit that model (e.g. a search results page), then perhaps it isn't worth providing ETags.

Comment: How do big sites handle this? For search results are they just sending back 50kb of html on every response with a new server template rendered on the fly, or ~30kb of json?

It doesn't seem plausible to cache every single search query and then do a lookup in your cache map against a combination of the template name and url query strings.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve through the ETags?  If you can't cheaply validate the ETags you generate, then it may not be worth while bothering.  I mentioned search results as an example of data that is difficult to generate an etag for, and may not be worth bothering with due to its high volatility (e.g. Google search results don't provide ETags).

Comment: Trying to cut down on outgoing bandwidth on the server and in some cases improve response time for the user.

Comment: If outgoing bandwidth is the primary concern, then buffering the response and then calculating a hash to use as an ETag is an option (along with correct handling of conditional requests).  If you want to improve response time, then you probably want an ETag that is cheaper to calculate (which may require changes to your data model).

Comment: That's the whole point of my post, trying to find the cheapest etag that actually works or even a way to rig in last-modified for dynamic content instead of etags.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an efficient [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) mechanism and don't need something cryptographically strong, I would suggest using CRC-32.  To help prevent collisions, you could combine a few things like the template name, length of the data, and the crc:

```
func etag(name string, data []byte) string {
    crc := crc32.ChecksumIEEE(data)
    return fmt.Sprintf(`W/"%s-%d-%08X"`, name, len(data), crc)
}
```

[This](http://play.golang.org/p/PyPMccIjYs) will produce an etag like `W/"tpl-17-3074C885"`.

Comment: That is basically what I'm doing now. The problem is calculating a crc32 from "data" is a serious bottleneck when the data could easily be 25kb+ in size (returning results from a db, etc.).

I see no viable way to use last-modified either because template data could change without the file's modified time being changed. Think: search results or even something as simple as ouputting hello [user] on the top of every page.

Comment: What is the smallest thing that is unique to the output?  That's what you have to hash.  There's no way around it, and CRC-32 is going to be one of the cheapest hashes you have.

If the same query always produces the same output, then you could hash the input instead (probably with something more collision-resistant like SHA-1).  If not, you might have to do some restructuring such that you do know modification times, and can go that route.

Comment: The smallest thing would be a username I suppose, similar to stackoverflow how it shows your user name on the top of every page.

If I render a server side template and plop in the user name into the template then it'll be different for every user. At this point the entire template result couldn't be cached right? If you and I both view /foo, our results are different because our usernames are not the same.

That is just one example.